# unable to call jquery datetimepicker function in custom directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have made a custom directive in angularJs which is used to show datetimepicker.

```
app.directive("timePicker", function() {
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                    //On click
                    $(elem).click(function() {
                        $(this).datetimepicker();
                    });
                }
            };
        });
```

used it like this in html

```
<div>
            <input type="text" name="basic_example_1" id="basic_example_1" value="" class="hasDatepicker" 
            time-picker>
        </div>
```

I am using following js files.

```
<script src='appResources/js/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js'></script> 
<script src='appResources/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js'></script>
<script src='appResources/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon-i18n.min.js'></script>
<link href="appResources/css/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I am referring from this site to get datetimepicker
[here](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#basic_examples)

Comment: this post might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376112/can-i-use-a-jquery-plugin-from-within-an-angularjs-directive/27376896#27376896

Answer (score 0):

try to use only:

```
jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js
```

and check console log, maybe there are errors